# How to configure Time Machine to also backup an connected external hard drive?

Tags: macos, backup, external-hard-drive, time-machine

I've inserted a sweet SSD into my MacBook Pro, but it had limited space. So I had to export 60 GB of Data to an external hard drive. But now, when I run TimeMachine to backup my stuff, of course it only backups what's on the system disk.

Is there a way how to also backup the connected external hard drive together with TimeMachine? Maybe there's a trick to get this work, with a fake folder that's actually the mounted drive? What could I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go in System Preferences to Time machine and choose Options You should see a list of things NOT to be backed up. Your connected drive probably shows here and if so you can remove it from the list.